# Getting MySQL data from a taglist and a direct search

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a search in my database. At the same time I have a tagging system installed. Not everything is tagged yet, so I also need the 'old fashioned' result from my database. Let me make it clear:

```
Table A
+----+----------------------------+
| ID | description                |
+----+----------------------------+
|  0 | horse going bad            |
|  1 | Older Years of Resolutions |
|  2 | The pirate                 |
|  3 | The Wish list              |
|  4 | list that's no list        |
+----+----------------------------+

table TAGS
+----+------------+
| ID | tag        |
+----+------------+
|  0 | list       |
|  1 | knockknock |
+----+------------+

table TAGLINKS
+-------+--------+
| TAGID | JOKEID |
+-------+--------+
|   0   |    2   |
|   0   |    3   |
+-------+--------+
```

When I do this search:

```
select * from A where locate('list',description)
```

I'll get ID 3 and 4 from table A, which is great.

When I do this search:

```
select * from tags
   join taglinks on tagid=tags.id
   join A on A.id=jokeid
where tag='list'
```

I get ID 2 and 3 from table A.

What I want to get back is ID 2, 3 and 4. So a join of the two results. I tried this:

```
select * from tags
   join taglinks on tagid=tags.id
   join A on A.id=jokeid or locate('list',description)
```

It seems to give me the right result, but it's so slow it clogs up the server (in reality the tables are MUCH bigger than the examples here). The reason I want a combined query is that I need functions like ORDER BY and LIMIT. So I'm looking to get the combined result from the above two queries.

Comment: What stops you from just `UNION`ing the two fast queries?

Comment: union is the solution for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eugen Rieck and Raheel Shan pointed out the answer is a union:

```
select A.* from tags
  join taglinks on tagid=tags.id
  join A on A.id=jokeid
where tag="list"
UNION
select * from A where locate("list",description)
```

Gives me ID 2, 3 and 4